# Having trouble getting values when creating new table

Tags: mysql, sql

Fairly new to SQL - Using MySQL with PhpMyAdmin - I have two CSV sheets that have information that need to be merged into a new CSV while removing all other inapplicable columns. The columns I need are email, user_id, and need to create a new column titled "role"

The email column is different on each file, and the end result would be 74 lines, not 100 (not all emails will match). So far, I've been able to use join to get the columns I need. What I'm struggling with is creating a new table with "role" and having the data transfer over.

The table is created, with the right columns, but the values from example and test do not appear.

What I started with:

```
Select example.user_name,
test.email
from example
join test
on example.user_email = test.email
```

Where I got to:

```
CREATE table test2 (role text)
select email, user_name
from (
Select example.user_name,test.email
from example
join test
on example.user_email = test.email)
As Test
```

I've been at this for 4 hours (took me a good chunk of time just to get to this point) and this hurdle has been the most difficult. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Table 1 Example. 
User ID :1111. 
User_email: example.com. 

Table 2 Test   
first_name: Tom   
last_name: Laugh. 
email: example.com
```

The first query joins these two together. The third table would need to add "role" which would be a defined value and would look like

```
Table 3 All together. 
Role: onboarding. 
user_id: 1111. 
user_email: example.com
```

Hope that helps clarify things! Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. You're just taking data from one table and putting it into a newly-created table?

Comment: Provide a sample of source data (2-3 rows per table) and final state. *Where I got to* Implicit column specifying is not a good practice. *What I'm struggling with is creating a new table with "role" and having the data transfer over.* Where the data for `role` column should be taken?

Comment: @matigo - Joining data from table 1 & 2  that match then creating a third table with an added column and the data/value that was joined in the query if that makes sense

Comment: @Akina - Role would be either undefined or defined as "onboarding" - I haven't gotten that far yet in how to add that, I just want to get the data transferred over.

Comment: There's no `INSERT` statement shown. If you've included all statements you're running, that's the primary reason why you have a table, with columns, but no values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TABLE test2 ( user_email VARCHAR(255),
                     user_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
                     user_name VARCHAR(255),
                     role TEXT)
SELECT user_email, 
       example.user_id,
       CONCAT_WS(' ', test.first_name, test.last_name) user_name,
       'onboarding' role
FROM example
JOIN test USING (user_email);
```

1. Specify new table structure completely. This eliminates some possible problems in future (for example, you may obtain string columns which are shorter than you need).
2. Specify column names in SELECT part completely with strict matching to those in table definition - if not then destination columns would be empty but excess columns with unneeded (and sometimes strange) names will be added.
3. Always use absolutely the same names for matching columns in different tables until it is impossible.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5e7c77aa8ad2f5f44e1851bd3ebe17e7

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you for that! Creating the table first seems like a no brainer, not sure why i was making it so complicated.